# Kendo Pager (pageable) is showing 'No items to display' even if the record are there

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, pagination, kendo-grid

Here Ia m using Kendo-UI with Angular-JS.

Facing an issue while integrating Pagination (pageable) on Kendo grid table, it showing 'No items to display' even if the data (records) are loaded properly.

Not sure whats wrong with it, Any help would be appropriated...

Following is the function I am using to load/init the data grid.

```
function getProjectsAtAGlance() {
                $scope.gridOptions = {
                    scrollable: false,
                    sortable: true,
                    pageable: {
                        pageSizes: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50]
                    },
                    change: function (e) {
                        $scope.pageSize = $scope.gridOptions.dataSource.pageSize();
                    },
                    dataSource: {
                        serverPaging: true,
                        transport: {
                            read: function (options) {

                                $scope.options = options;

                                var filters = {
                                    skip: options.data.skip,
                                    take: options.data.take,
                                    sortBy: $scope.sortBy,
                                    projectGlanceIncludeArchived: $scope.includeArchivedProjects,
                                    projectGlanceExcludeProjectsWithNoBudgets: $scope.excludeProjectsWithNoBudgets
                                };

                                $http.post("/Home/ProjectsAtAGlanceReport", filters)
                                    .success(function (result) {
                                        var projects = result.projects;

                                        for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
                                            var project = projects[i];
                                            project.startDate = moment(projects[i].startDate).format("L");
                                            project.endDate = moment(projects[i].endDate).format("L");
                                        }

                                        options.success(projects);

                                    })
                                    .error(function (error) {
                                        console.log(error);
                                    });
                            }
                        },
                        pageSize: $scope.pageSize,

                        schema: {
                            total: function (respose) {
                                return $scope.data;
                            },

                            model: {
                                fields: {
                                    name: {
                                        editable: false,
                                        nullable: true
                                    },
                                    resourceCount: {
                                        editable: false,
                                        nullable: true
                                    },
                                    clientName: {
                                        editable: false,
                                        nullable: true
                                    },
                                    startDate: {
                                        editable: false,
                                        nullable: true
                                    },
                                    endDate: {
                                        editable: false,
                                        nullable: true
                                    },
                                    projectId: {
                                        editable: false,
                                        nullable: true
                                    },
                                    projectedBudgetPercentage: {
                                        defaultValue: 100
                                    },
                                    defaultValue: {
                                        totalBudget: 0,
                                        totalHours: 0,
                                        burnedBudget: 0,
                                        burnedHours: 0,
                                        projectedBudget: 0,                                         
                                        projectedHours: 0,
                                        projectedHoursPercentage: 0,
                                        remainingBudget: 0,
                                        remainingBudgetPercentage: 0,
                                        remainingHours: 0,
                                        remainingHoursPercentage: 0
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    columns: [
                        {
                            template: "<div class='name-column'>" +
                                "<p><a class='highlighted-blue' href='/Projects/ProjectAdmin/{{dataItem.projectId}}'>{{dataItem.name}}</a></p>" +
                                "<small>{{dataItem.clientName}}</small>" +
                                "<small ng-if=\"dataItem.startDate !== 'Invalid date'\">{{dataItem.startDate}} - {{dataItem.endDate}}</small>" +
                                "<small ng-if=\"dataItem.startDate === 'Invalid date'\"><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger'></i> Start date and end date are not defined.</small>" +
                                "<small>{{dataItem.resourceCount}} Resources</small></div>"

                        },
                        {
                            template: kendo.template($("#kendoProgressBarColumnTemplate").html())
                        },
                        {
                            template: "<accuracy-gauge-per-project accuracy='dataItem.accuracy'></accuracy-gauge-per-project>"
                        },
                        {
                            template:
                                "<p>{{dataItem.accuracy | percentage:0}} Accurate</p>" +
                                "<p>{{100-dataItem.accuracy | percentage:0}} Non Accurate</p>"
                        }
                    ]
                };
            }
```

Here is an output snippets for reference.
[image: Kendo Grid with Pagination]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [`pageSize`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-pageSize) attribute needs to be declared within the `dataSource` like so:

```
dataSource: {
    serverPaging: true,
    transport: {... // transport options
    },
    pageSize: $scope.pageSize // before end of dataSource       
},... // more grid stuff
```

And change what you are returning from `schema.total` to `return response.total` as per [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.total).

Comment: Another thing, what does `respose` contain in [`schema.total`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.total)? Should this function not `return respose.total`?

Comment: Yes Sandman, you are right, something is wrong with 'schema.total'.
I have removed "total: function (respose) {return $scope.data;}," to check and it's working fine now.

Comment: Glad to hear you have got it working. Please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it led to a solution. :)